# cURL not fetching the expected POST response - error 405

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, highcharts, http-status-code-405

I need to fetch several charts from the Highcharts export server (since I haven't implemented that feature on my own server yet).

Highcharts shows a very clear example here:
http://export.highcharts.com/demo

I tried to simulate that form using the curl command from Linux, successfully.

But, when trying to run curl from PHP (specifically from a CakePHP controller), I get a HTTP error:

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Something is wrong, since the POST method worked interactivelly from the navigator and from curl command.

Also, I tested the PHP script pointing it to posttestserver.com, a site intended to debugging the result of POST requests. The result of my test is here: http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2014/03/10/10.18.221071980127

This is the code of the method of the CakePHP controller:

```
public function obtenir() {

    $ch = curl_init("http://export.highcharts.com/demo");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            "content" => "options",
            "options" => "%7B%0D%0A%09xAxis%3A+%7B%0D%0A%09%09categories%3A+%5B%27Jan%27%2C+%27Feb%27%2C+%27Mar%27%2C+%27Apr%27%2C+%27May%27%2C+%27Jun%27%2C+%27Jul%27%2C+%27Aug%27%2C+%27Sep%27%2C+%27Oct%27%2C+%27Nov%27%2C+%27Dec%27%5D%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%0D%0A%09series%3A+%5B%7B%0D%0A%09%09data%3A+%5B29.9%2C+71.5%2C+106.4%2C+129.2%2C+144.0%2C+176.0%2C+135.6%2C+148.5%2C+216.4%2C+194.1%2C+95.6%2C+54.4%5D%0D%0A%09%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A",
            "type" => "image%2Fpng",
            "width" => "",
            "scale" => "",
            "constr" => "Chart",
            "callback" => "function%28chart%29+%7B%0D%0A%09chart.renderer.arc%28200%2C+150%2C+100%2C+50%2C+-Math.PI%2C+0%29.attr%28%7B%0D%0A%09%09fill+%3A+%27%23FCFFC5%27%2C%0D%0A%09%09stroke+%3A+%27black%27%2C%0D%0A%09%09%27stroke-width%27+%3A+1%0D%0A%09%7D%29.add%28%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%09%09%09",
            ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $page = curl_exec($ch);

    $head = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    debug($head);
    debug($page);

    curl_close($ch);

}
```

The result of debug($page) is an HTML formatted text with the significant content:

## HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Use `http_build_query()` for the post over your post parameter array. Otherwise its recognized as multipart form posting.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( array(...) ));
```

Please make sure the `POST` url is also correct.

Comment: Thanks @sabuj-hassan, it worked! The server gets the request but it shows a notice saying: "The manadatory svg POST parameter is undefined." even if I add it on the param array. And the fact is that it worked from the command line without the svg field.

Comment: Finally, it works. I just passed to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS an array of clean (unencoded) values passed through http_build_query() only once as you reported, to solve the last issue.

Also, I had to delete the trailing "demo" on curl_init, since in the original form, the action is "./" (the current directory), to solve the initial issue.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ur URL is wrong, change:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://export.highcharts.com/demo");
```

to

```
$ch = curl_init("http://export.highcharts.com");
```